# Delete row from a listview

Tags: android, listview, row

I want to delete a row in a listview. I'm using a DataBaseOpenHelper. The rows contain two fields: id_persona and name.

```
myListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
               public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                     int id_person = HOW !!!!!!!!
                     personasDBAdapter.deletePerson(id_person);
               }
});
```

How can I get the id_persona field in a row? I don't want the row position. I've already implemented the method deletePerson in the DataBaseOpenHelper class.

```
                 id_person  name
row 1 listview         234  John
row 2 listview         138  Anna
row 3 listview          64  Phil
```

I want '234' or '138', not row 1 or row 2.

Comment: Get the `Object` that is being used at position `i` using `personasDBAdapter.getItem(i)`. Retrieve `id_person` field value from the object after casting.

Comment: Hi, I'm new to Android, what should be the method getItem(int i) in personasDBAdapter class and how I should the casting? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of the onItemsLongClick looks like this:

```
onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

So whats "int i" in your code actually is the position of the item in your adapter.

To access the item call adapter.getItem(postion).

```
Person person = (Person)adapter.getItem(postion);
int id = person.getIdPersona();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int id_person = i
```

Which gives you the index of the row, then

```
.remove(adapter.getItem(i));
```